# Force no prompt in apt-get upgrade or apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, apt-get, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using AWS EC2 14.04 LTS and I'm trying to run command 
`apt-get -y upgrade` or `apt-get -y dist-upgrade`, however, I always get prompt like this:

[image]
I tried following commands and none of them work and I still get above prompt:

`apt-get update && apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" dist-upgrade`

`apt-get update && apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' --force-yes -fuy dist-upgrade`

I have been been googling for solutions but could not find that actually works. Anyone has any thought?

Thanks

Comment: no, I have not found a solution yet!

Comment: @Hackeron I just found out my solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out the simple solution. I could avoid the prompt by adding `DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold'`

So here is my common function that I use to upgrade all my Ubuntu machines:

```
function runAptGetUpgrade()
{
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' upgrade
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' dist-upgrade

    apt-get autoremove -y
    apt-get clean
    apt-get autoclean
}
```

REF My Lib: https://github.com/gdbtek/ubuntu-cookbooks/blob/master/libraries/util.bash

REF Answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/479571/running-apt-get-upgrade-with-chef-solo

Comment: What's your solution for a noninteractive `do-release-upgrade` with old configs by default?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a workaround here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265877